# PHP SQL Database Information not displaying

Tags: php

I have been trying to display some test information from the database, but I've tried to get the information to echo.
Currently the echo and the if statement is working as intended, but the variables from the database are not displaying.

This is the navbar linking code, linking with pgname and displaying title

```
        <?php foreach($recordStorage as $pageinfo): ?>
        <a href="index.php?page='<?php echo $pageinfo['pgname']; ?>'" class="nav-link"><?php echo $pageinfo['title']; ?></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the index display code (I removed the majority of variables to keep the code short)

```
 <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['page']))
        {
        $pgname = trim($_Get['page'], "'");
        
        $recordStorage = $connection->query("select * from scp_pages where pgname='$pgname'") or die($connection->error());

        //Creates into array for display
        $display = $recordStorage->fetch_assoc();

        $title = $display['title'];
        $class = $display['class'];   

        echo "
        
        <h1>{$title}</h1>
        <h2> Object Class {$class}</h2>
 

        }
        else
        {
            echo "
            <h1>Welcome to this website</h1>
        }
        ?>
```

and finally this is the database display, from what I saw, everything was running decently

```
<?php

    $user = "database_testuser";
    $password = "1234567890";
    $database = "database_name";

    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $recordStorage = $connection->query("select * from scp_pages") or die($connection->error());

?>
```

Comment: Dump `$display` property.

Comment: By the way, consider using PDO to build the query, to avoid sql injection.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: Neither `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` nor `or die($connection->error())` is correct. You need to remove both of them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for telling me about SQL_Injections and further issues with my code, I will get to fixing it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably in the following statement:

`$pgname = trim($_Get['page'], "'");`

Instead of `$_Get`, the expected syntax is in uppercase: `$_GET`

After changing this, dump the `$pgname` var to see if it has the expected value.